# Regex, match everything, except double asterisks

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I am creating a text editor interface where the user is able to format the text, and he can see the modifications in a div next to it.

To highlight a bunch of text, I reserved double asterisks as the following ** **text** **, just like here in stackoverflow.

My code looks like the following:

```
replace(/\*{2}([^\*]*)\*{2}/g, "<strong>$1</strong>")
```

but my problem is, if the text is including an asterisk, the following output can be seen:

** text* **,

and not **text***

how is it possible to negate double characters for matching to not break the HTML tag in the output?

Comment: As usual, this is a half-baked request, missing info. What can go `**`<here>abc<here>`**` Don't just say a _space_ because then it becomes part of the delimiter. There is only 1 answer style that fits, it's `\*\*.*?\*\*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deal with single asterisks followed by at least one other character just adding `(?:\*[^*]+)*`:

```
yourstr = yourstr.replace(/\*\*([^*]*(?:\*[^*]+)*)\*\*/g, "<strong>$1</strong>");
```

Note that escaping `*` in a character class is useless, and writing `\*{2}` is longer than `\*\*`.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! This solution is perfect for my need! The explanation is clear!